# можно ли поставить ini_set("memory_limit", "-1")

Tags: php, debian, битрикс

Просто выполнение скрипта выдает ошибку. (Он ресурсоемкий, планируется запускаться в течение дня, пока ночью работает, занимается переносом товаров из 1с в битрикс!)

> PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 2147483648 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 1609302016 bytes) in /var/www/admin/www/test.ru/bitrix/modules/iblock/classes/general/cml2_metrika_import_fon.php on line 1099

на этой строчке стоит вывод

```
echo "finish;CIBlockElement::SetElementSection;".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."\n";
```

Я хотела определить время каждой операции для каждого товара. А элементов -10000000. Но видимо, пока скрипт не выполнится, то не записывается в лог. И следовательно, эти `echo` попадают в оперативную память, и скрипт тормозит. Верно?
Я запускаю скрипт в фоновом режиме.
http://prntscr.com/9nvnx3

Что лучше предпринять? Спасибо!
В самом скрипте стоит ограничение `ini_set('memory_limit', '2048M');`

Comment: А сколько у вас оперативной памяти на сервере?)

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, http://prntscr.com/9nvtp2

Comment: Смотрите на ответ от @Ипатьев. Что-то мне подсказывает, что просто снятие ограничений на объем памяти вам все равно не поможет.

Answer (score 2):

> можно ли поставить ini_set(“memory_limit”, “-1”)

Можно.

Но нужно понимать, что эта директива не увеличит количество физической памяти, доступной РНР скрипту. И если этот скрипт написан криво, то его не спасут никакие директивы настройки и никакое количество выделенной памяти.

Поэтому вместо игр с `memory_limit` надо писать скрипт так, чтобы память в нем не утекала.

Буферизация вывода тут вряд ли виновата, поскольку для консольных скриптов она в РНР оключена. Но если используется устаревшая версия РНР, то столь любимый пользователями пхп output buffering следует отключить:

```
ini_set('output_buffering', 0);
```

Надо искать утечку памяти и исправлять её. До тех пор, пока скрипт переноса данных не будет занимать больше 8 мегабайт.

В частности, данные при переносе надо записывать сразу, а не копить в памяти

Чтобы найти место утечки, в выводимую отладочную информацию следует добавить вывод `memory_get_usage()`

при этом надо разбивать скрипт на атомарные операции. В частности, никто не может сказать, сколько памяти требует вызов CIBlockElement::SetElementSection. то есть его надо вызывать отдельно, и замерять использование памяти до и после

Comment: Сразу записывать в файл вместо конструкции `echo`?

Comment: ,у меня на сервере акселлатор не установлен, может причина в нем? Какой лучше?

Comment: Это все не при чем. Я написал выше, что надо сделать. Если примтивный скрипт экспорта отъедает 2 гига памяти, то надо не память увеличивать, а увольнять программиста